# Exponentially weighted infinite sum of Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Consider the following process.  For each integer $i \geq 0$, independently sample a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p = 1/2$, obtaining sample $x_i$.  Then calculate $x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \theta^i,$ where $(\theta < 1)$.  What is the distribution over $x$?

I see that if θ = 0.5 then this is a uniformly generated binary number between 0 and 2.  [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268881/limit-distribution-of-infinite-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables) is closely related, but I don't see how the method given there (with θ = 0.5) generalizes to arbitrary $\theta$.  I am interested in values of $\theta$ close to 1, such as $\theta = 0.95$.

I am ultimately interested in a hypothesis test:  $H_0=$ "$p = 0.5$" against the alternative $H_A=$ "$p \neq 0.5$".  The motivation is, I am receiving an infinite sequence of 0s and 1s for which I only retain an exponentially weighted average (not recording the whole sequence).  And based on this weighted average I want to decide whether the 0s and 1s were generated with equal probability or not.

Edit: based on an empirical test it appears to be roughly normally distributed.  The following was generated by performing a 100,000 sample run with $\theta = 0.95$.  It has mean 10 and variance 2.5.

```
 5.9 
 6.0 
 6.1 *
 6.2 *
 6.3 *
 6.4 *
 6.5 **
 6.6 **
 6.7 **
 6.8 ***
 6.9 ***
 7.0 ****
 7.1 *****
 7.2 *****
 7.3 ******
 7.4 ******
 7.5 ********
 7.6 ********
 7.7 *********
 7.8 *********
 7.9 **********
 8.0 ************
 8.1 ************
 8.2 *************
 8.3 **************
 8.4 ***************
 8.5 ****************
 8.6 *****************
 8.7 ******************
 8.8 *******************
 8.9 *******************
 9.0 ********************
 9.1 *********************
 9.2 **********************
 9.3 ***********************
 9.4 **********************
 9.5 ***********************
 9.6 ***********************
 9.7 *************************
 9.8 ************************
 9.9 ************************
10.0 ************************
10.1 ************************
10.2 *************************
10.3 ************************
10.4 ***********************
10.5 ***********************
10.6 **********************
10.7 ***********************
10.8 **********************
10.9 *********************
11.0 *******************
11.1 *******************
11.2 ******************
11.3 ******************
11.4 ****************
11.5 ***************
11.6 ***************
11.7 *************
11.8 ************
11.9 ************
12.0 ***********
12.1 **********
12.2 *********
12.3 ********
12.4 ********
12.5 *******
12.6 ******
12.7 *****
12.8 *****
12.9 *****
13.0 ****
13.1 ***
13.2 ***
13.3 **
13.4 **
13.5 **
13.6 *
13.7 *
13.8 *
13.9 *
14.0 
14.1
```

Normal quantile plot for $\theta=0.90$:
[image: Normal quantile plot for theta=0.90]
Normal quantile plot for $\theta=0.95$:
[image: Normal quantile plot for theta=0.95]

Looks like it has thin tails.

Comment: Maybe work with different, not decimal, system? When it is 1\2, you can use binary code. If it is 1\n i suppose you can do something similiar?

Comment: $\theta = \frac12$ is a critical value: below $\frac12$ there will either be a unique $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ giving the sum $x$ or no such sequence, while above $\frac12$ there will be multiple $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ corresponding to plausible $x$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Suppose $\theta =0.1$.  Then you are suggesting the support is $[0,1.1111\ldots]$ and that does give the range of potential values. But I think for example no values in the open interval $(0.1111\ldots,1)$ are in the support.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, but what to do after that?

Comment: Maybe some CLT with non-iid variables can be used?

Comment: @Henry I see now. The support of this distribution is not so straightforward.

Comment: Well, we know that the variance will be exactly $p(1-p) / (1 - \theta^2)$ just by the linearity of variance.  However I did a normal quantile plot and it looks like the tails are thinner than a normal distribution.

Comment: @causative the distribution can be highly nonnormal.  Try smaller values of $\theta<0.5$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Sure, that's interesting too.  Mostly I want to know about getting a good approximation to the distribution when $\theta$ is near 1 for my application.  (If a closed form can't be found.)

Answer (score 4):

This type of distribution has a long history. If you apply an affine map $x \mapsto 2x-1$, you may assume the Bernoulli variables take values $\pm 1$. Then the laws of these sums have been studied under the name "Infinite Bernoulli convolutions", see [1], [2] for surveys. The basic result is that for a.e. $\theta \in (1/2,1)$ the laws are absolutely continuous; the exceptions have Hausdorff dimension zero, and all known exceptions are algebraic numbers (in fact, inverse Pisot numbers.)

[1] Peres, Yuval, Wilhelm Schlag, and Boris Solomyak. "Sixty years of Bernoulli convolutions." In Fractal geometry and stochastics II, pp. 39-65. Birkhäuser, Basel, 2000.

[2] Varjú, Péter P. "Recent progress on Bernoulli convolutions." arXiv preprint arXiv:1608.04210 (2016).

Comment: Is there a good way to efficiently calculate or approximate the cumulative distribution function for $\theta$ near 1?

Comment: This is tangentially related to your posting. Does the convolution of the Cantor-1/3 distribution $\mu_{1/3}$ with itself has a nontrivial absolute continuous (w.r.t. Lebesgue's measure $\lambda$) part? I know (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596527/121671)) that $\mu_{1/3}*\mu_{1/3}\not\ll \lambda$) and that if $C$ is the 1/3 Cantor set, $C+C=[0,1]$. If you have any reference, please let me know. I can also post this as a question and if you have time to write about it, I would also appreciate it.

Comment: @Oliver Díaz
 This measure is purely singular, and carried by a set of Hausdorff dimension  $<1$. If you post it as a question and let me know, I can add more details.

Comment: @YuvalPeres: Thanks! I just posted a question. Is there any $n$ for which $\mu^{*n}_{1/3}$ has a density?

Comment: @Oliver Díaz  The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma shows that there is no such $n$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres: I meant to ask whether the absolutely continuous part of $\mu^{*n}_{1/3}$ is not zero.

Comment: @Oliver Díaz the absolutely continuous part of the $n$-fold convolution of $\mu_3$ is zero for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Here I address the main concern of the OP with regards the behavior of the distribution of $X^{(\theta)}=\sum_{n\geq1}\varepsilon_n\theta^n$ for $0<\theta<1$ close to $1$, where
with $(\varepsilon_n)$ and i.i.d sequence of Bernoulli 0-1 random variables.

### A few observations:

The law $\mu_\theta$ of $X^{(\theta)}$,  $0<\theta<1$,  may exhibit quite strange behavior. For example:

1. when $\theta=1/3$, the law of $Y=2X^{(\theta)}$ happens to be the devil stair's distribution and $Y$ is concentrated in the 1/3 Cantor set.
2. When $\theta=1/2$, this corresponds to the Lebesgue measure in $(0,1)$ (a.k.a uniform distribution in (0,1). This is not surprising as this correspond to choosing the digits of a number in binary expansion by tossing a fair coin.
3. The support of the law $\mu_\theta$ of $X^{(\theta)}$ is contained in $[0,\theta(1-\theta)^{-1}]$.

**Claim:** $X^{(\theta)}$ converges vaguely to $0$  as $\theta\rightarrow1$.

Motivation:

The Lapalace transform of the law of $X^{(\theta)}$ is given by
\begin{align}
E\big[e^{-tX^{(\theta)}}\big] = \prod_{n\geq1} E\big[e^{-t\epsilon_n\theta^n}\big]= \prod_{n\geq1}\frac{1+e^{-t\theta^n}}{2} =: g(t,\theta)
\end{align}
($t>0$) which is increasing in $\theta$. In particular, $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow1-}g(t,\theta)$ exists.

Notice that if $\theta=1$, then the product above is $0$. This is no surprising since the Bernoulli (0,1) random walk diverges to $\infty$ a.s. This suggests that
as $\theta\rightarrow1-$,  the law $\mu_\theta$ of $X^{(\theta)}$ converges vaguely to $0$;  in other words, as  $\theta\rightarrow1-$, all the mass is being moved to infinity.

**Proof of claim**: The crux of the problem is to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\theta\rightarrow1}g(t,\theta) = 0 \tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
For if this is indeed th case, then for any $a>0$

$$
P[X^{(\theta)}\leq a]\leq e^a g(a,\theta)\xrightarrow{\theta\rightarrow1-}0
$$

Now, for fixed $t>0$,
$$\Phi_\theta(\omega)=e^{-Yt^{(\theta)}(\omega)}$$
is uniformly bounded $0<\Phi_\theta\leq1$,  monotone noninreasing in $\theta$ (i.e. $\Phi_\theta\leq\Phi_{\theta'}$ if $\theta'<\theta$), and $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow1}\Phi_\theta=0$ almost surely since $\sum_n\epsilon_n=\infty$ almost surely. By dominated convergence
$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow1-}E\big[e^{-tX^{(\theta)}}\big]=E\big[\lim_{\theta\rightarrow1-}e^{-tX^{(\theta)}}\big]=0$

---

### Final comments:

- On the other extreme, when $\theta=0$ then $X^{(\theta)}\equiv0$. Hence, as with $1$, the law $\mu_\theta$ converges vaguely (in fact  weakly) to $\delta_0$. This case can also been  proven by dominated convergence.
- The symmetric version of the problem, namely
  $$Z^{(\theta)}:=2 X^{(\theta)}-\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}=\sum_{n\geq1}\xi_n\theta^n$$
  where the $\xi_n=2\epsilon_n-1$ form an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli $\pm1$ random variables with parameter $p=1/2$,  explains why there seem to be some symmetry around some number ($\theta/(1-\theta)$) in the QQplots shown by the OP.
- The study of the law of $Z^{(\theta)}$, $0<\theta<1$, is a classical problem in Probability consider by Erdös, and a great source of interesting results and open questions.

Comment: If $\theta = 1$ and $t > 0$ then $\prod_n (1 + e^{t \theta^n})/2$ is an infinite product of terms > 1.